# windows phone notification from app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an app which provides PNR status of indian railways.I store PNR numbers.Is there a way to track changes in status of PNR internally when app is closing and display changes to user via notification?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Some things to think about when posting is the following. 1. We have no idea what a PNR is. Please provide as much detail as possible. 2. What have you tried? Please always post some sort of code unless its totally impossible. Finally please make sure to format your question as clearly as possible. Can't wait to help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Push Notifications are what you are looking for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx